# DESFire authentication with AES

Tags: security, authentication, aes, mifare, contactless-smartcard

If I do an authentication to a DESFire card using AES, do I need to do the key diversification? If so, is there some code example of how to do the diversification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't *have* to use a diversified key. You can just as well use the same key(s) for all your DESFire cards. However, it is advisable to use a diversified key in order to prevent attacks on the whole system if an attacker discovers the key(s) for one card.

With regard to key diversification functions, I suggest that you take a look at [NXP's application note on Symmetric key diversifications](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10922.pdf).